# Rails 4 NoMethodError in Products#index using helper_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to add a simple stock control system to my rails app
Added a stock field to the existing products database

created a helper method called `print_stock` and have added this to the `Products#index` file
but when i run the app get

```
NoMethodError in Products#index, undefined method `print_stock' for #<#Class:0x007f821b670530>:0x007f821e170898>
```

add stock to products

```
class AddStockToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :stock, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

**index.html**

```
<tbody>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= image_tag "products/#{product.image_url}" %></td>
        <td><%= product.title %></td>
        <td><%= print_price(product.price) %></td>
        **<td><%= print_stock(product.stock) %></td>**<---error
        <td><%= product.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', product_path(product) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

**print.stock.rb**

```
def print_stock(stock)
  if stock > 0
    <span class="in_stock">In Stock (XX)</span>
  else
    <span class="out_stock">Out of Stock</span>
  end
end
```

updated applicationhelper

```
module ApplicationHelper
def print_stock(stock)
    if stock > 0
      "<span class="in_stock">In Stock (XX)</span>"
    else
      "<span class="out_stock">Out of Stock</span>"
    end
  end
end

/Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/merchant/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end "<span class="in_stock">In Stock (XX)</span>" ^ /Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/merchant/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end "<span class="out_stock">Out of Stock</span>" ^
```

**updated products_helper**

```
module ProductsHelper

    def print_price(price)
        format("£%.2f",price)
    end

  def print_stock(stock)
    if stock.to_i > 0
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helper file name should be:

```
products_helper.rb
```

and the contents should be:

```
module ProductsHelper
  def print_stock(stock)
    if stock.to_i > 0
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Then in View:

```
index.html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= image_tag "products/#{product.image_url}" %></td>
        <td><%= product.title %></td>
        <td><%= print_price(product.price) %></td>


        <td>
           <% if print_stock(product.stock) %>
              <span class="in_stock">In Stock (XX)</span>
           <% else %>
              <span class="out_stock">Out of Stock</span>
           <% end %>
        </td>

        <td><%= product.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', product_path(product) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: What error? do you have stock column in your table and have value?

Comment: add_column :products, :stock, :integer, default: 0

Comment: did you run the migration? what is the error that you are getting using my answer?

Comment: yes ran migration create    db/migrate/20140426102622_add_stock_to_products.rb
Neils-MacBook-Pro:merchant neilpatel$ rake db:migrate
== 20140426102622 AddStockToProducts: migrating will try your answer again===============================
-- add_column(:products, :stock, :integer, {:default=>0})
   -> 0.0768s
== 20140426102622 AddStockToProducts: migrated (0.0770s) ======================

Comment: yes working now . thanks it now shows out of stock. what does if stock.to_i > 0 mean because i was using stock > 0

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines in **application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def print_stock(stock)
    if stock > 0
      "<span class="in_stock">In Stock (XX)</span>"
    else
      "<span class="out_stock">Out of Stock</span>"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the return values should be enclosed in apostrophes `'<span class="in_stock">In Stock (XX)</span>'`

Comment: added the lines in application_helper.rb and got errors syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end "<span class="in_stock">In Stock (XX)</span>" ^

Answer (score 0):

same answer but need to change some syntax

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def print_stock(stock)
  if stock > 0
   "<span class='in_stock'>In Stock (XX)</span>"
  else
   "<span class='out_stock'>Out of Stock</span>"
 end
end
```

end

need to change to `single quotes`